# Vertical Navigation Drawer using css, bootstrap, html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create vertical navigation drawer which will open bottom to top like following image.

[image]

I am very new to Bootstrap. I tried following code but it open from left to right.

Please go through following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried [this](http://www.bootply.com/114896#) link but no luck.

Please give me some reference or hint.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: absolute; bottom: 0px;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I changed the `ul.topnav.responsive` position to be absolute (It could also be fixed, and the position of `ul.topnav` and gave it a `width: 100%`, and I set the position of both of the elements to be `bottom: 0px`.

This could be refactored though because it should use an external stylesheet, and javascript file, and there ais styling directly on the `a` which is bad practice. It's also bad practice to have `href="javascript:void(0);"`, since the link is just triggering the javascript function why not use a button, or if you want to uses an `a` tag just remove the `href`.